# Export one csv file instead of 5

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have written the below code.  The logic is:
1.  a list of part numbers is inputted
2.  a price will be returned for each part from the database on the website
3.  The part might belong to one of the five companies, so 5 csv files are generated.

For example below is the initial list of part numbers (input):
b123
nadsf
ower
weoa

The output will be 5 csv files, returning price only for parts belonging to that company. In this case only 'ower' belongs to company A, so only one price is returned, and 5 different csv files will be generated for all 5 companies

```
0     
1     
2     3.5
3
```

Please see below for my code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\test_Trish.xlsx')
PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Product code'])

i = 0

Total_rows = PN.shape[0]
partnumlist = []
partnumlist1 = []
partnumlist2 = []   
partnumlist3 = []
partnumlist4 = []


while i < Total_rows:

         data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
         r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data).json()

         partnumlist.append(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data1 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17475"}}
         r1 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data1).json()

         partnumlist1.append(r1['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data2 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "16880"}}
         r2 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data2).json()

         partnumlist2.append(r2['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data3 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "47221"}}
         r3 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data3).json()

         partnumlist3.append(r3['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data4 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17045"}}
         r4 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data4).json()

         partnumlist4.append(r4['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         i=i+1

pd.DataFrame(partnumlist).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output21.csv')
pd.DataFrame(partnumlist1).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output22.csv')
pd.DataFrame(partnumlist2).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output23.csv')
pd.DataFrame(partnumlist3).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output24.csv')
pd.DataFrame(partnumlist4).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output25.csv')
```

What I want is to combine the csv files, so instead of 5 files I want only one file returning all prices:

0    1.5

1    24

2    3.5

3    231

Any help/suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Do all of the dataframes have the same amount of columns?

Comment: if Edeki's question is true, then just append the dfs together and write one

Comment: Yes, they all have same amount of columns.  The problem is though is if I simply combine them using say concat, I get 5 columns - I only want one.  If the part number does not belong to the company the price will simply be 0.  So if right now the 5 columns are 1000 0100 0010 0001 0000, I only want one column as 1111.  Hopefully I made myself clear this time...

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the dataframes before exporting to csv. There are a number of ways to combine data frames, such as `.merge()`, `.join()` and `.concat()`. My guess it that `.concat()` will be what you're after.

```
list_of_dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(partnumlist),pd.DataFrame(partnumlist1),
               pd.DataFrame(partnumlist2),pd.DataFrame(partnumlist3)
               pd.DataFrame(partnumlist4)]

pandas.concat(list_of_dataframes,axis=1).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output25.csv')
```

Comment: if I simply combine them using say concat, I get 5 columns - I only want one. If the part number does not belong to the company the price will simply be 0. So if right now the 5 columns are 1000 0100 0010 0001 0000, I only want one column as 1111. Hopefully I made myself clear this time...

Comment: Still not sure I understand then sorry. Two suggestions. `pandas.concat(list_of_dataframes,axis=1)` will concatenate lengthways instead of sideways (changed answer to reflect this).
Another option is to look at pd.combine_first. combine_first will look for data in the first column, and if it is NaN then it will get the data from the second column. You would replace zeros with np.nan first, and keep the columns side by side.